# union query to combine fields

Tags: ms-access

I don;t know SQL, so I am hoping that someone can provide me the SQL to copy and paste in order to merge all of the different unit price fields into one field called "merged_unit_price". Please note that many of the unit price values are null, so I would prefer that the null values don't get merged.
Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
SELECT  p.ID AS Part_ID, 
    p.UNIT_PRICE, 
    d.UNIT_PRICE_1, 
    d.UNIT_PRICE_2, 
    d.UNIT_PRICE_3
FROM    tbl_local_SYSADM_PART AS p 
LEFT JOIN SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE AS d 
ON p.ID = d.PART_ID;
```

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Do you want the lowest value? Do you want them added together? Often these kind of questions involved sample data, such as a this is what I have and this is what I want sort of thing. There really isn't enough information to definitively answer your question right now.

Comment: I was originally requesting to output a separate record for each value, but ideally the query would just  output the lowest value and the field would be called  "lowest_unit_price".  I originally intended to use a 2nd query to run a "min" function, in order to obtain the desired output of the lowest unit price. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off in your query make sure to exclude the `Null` values from you dataset.  Cant remember if Access SQL uses Null or Nothing, so try it one way and see if it errors out.

```
SELECT  p.ID AS Part_ID, p.UNIT_PRICE, d.UNIT_PRICE_1, d.UNIT_PRICE_2, d.UNIT_PRICE_3
FROM    tbl_local_SYSADM_PART AS p 
  LEFT JOIN SYSADM_DISCOUNT_PRICE AS d ON p.ID = d.PART_ID;
WHERE p.UNIT_PRICE <> Nothing OR p.UNIT_PRICE_1 <> NOTHING OR p.UNIT_PRICE_2 <> NOTHING OR p.UNIT_PRICE_3 <> Nothing
```

As well, i would suggest you learn more about SQL statements, in general and access, cause you have limited yourself to just 4 `UNIT_PRICE`'s and will eventually have to increase your table field signature.  If it were me, i would break this table into Join Table, so you can have multiple `Part_ID`'s and multiple `UNIT_PRICE`'s.  Currently you are restricted with one `Part_ID` and figuratively just one `UNIT_PRICE` (counting the 4 price fields as 1 record).

Comment: @Nathaniel_613: Although my query above does not concatenate the `Unit_Price` fields, in Access you can simply concatenate the desired fields into a single return field by using the `&` or `+`, cant remember right off hand which it is, as i do MS-SQL and Access development alot lately.